How to clearly separate rotate and edit gesture for 3D model in touch screen
For example, assuming you're using a lasso to select an area of a 3d model, you probably want to swipe your index finger to draw a shape(notice that selection can start from outside the model). Also since it's a 3d model, you'll need to rotate it and pan it in many cases, and the common way of rotating 3d model on a touch screen is also swiping with one finger, panning would be with 2 fingers.
So here's the problem, the select and rotate gestures are conflicting. I come up with those solutions:

put an obvious 'rotate' button to switch mode from select and rotate
when you're not activating any lasso or other select tools, you swipe to rotate, when you turn on the lasso, you'll be selecting and can not rotate
when you activate a select tool, the gesture for rotating would be swipe with 2 fingers, panning would be 3 fingers (no I don't like this)

Which one is better? Is there any other more user-friendly way to solve the conflict? I appreciate any suggestions
